# Initiliazing ParseLoginUI?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Where does one actually place the code to launch the ParseLoginUI activity?

```
ParseLoginBuilder builder = new ParseLoginBuilder(MainActivity.this);
startActivityForResult(builder.build(), 0);
```

Is it in the ParseLoginDispatchActivity? This was not made very clear at all within any of the official documentation:

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android

https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#user-interface

I'm importing ParseLoginUI into my existing app. What do I once I've installed everything, updated my manifests, my build.gradle and now want to actually launch the Login activity once my app launches?

Do I put something in my manifest to indicate that the ParseLoginActivity should launch first? That doesn't seem to work as an Activity from my main application is required to launch as the initial intent. I'm a little lost here... Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution would be to add the following to the onCreate method in the Activity that launches when your app launches. So if when your app launches you land on FirstActivity, the following will check to see if you are logged in. If you are not, you will be sent the login screen, and if you are logged in you will be sent to the second Activity, which is presumably where your users will want to be when they open your app.

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
if (currentUser != null) {
    Intent launchMainActivity = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(launchMainActivity );
} else {
    ParseLoginBuilder builder = new ParseLoginBuilder(FirstActivity.this);
    startActivityForResult(builder.build(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I did find one solution, albeit a trivial one:

```
Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ParseLoginActivity.class); startActivity(loginIntent);
```

I launched the above Intent with an options menu item, but you could do it with a button or whatever else suits your needs.

If you're importing ParseLoginUI into an existing app, it appears you can just launch ParseLoginActivity with a simple Intent. I wish they mentioned this on their integration tutorial. Seems like the most straightforward way to get it running.

This solution definitely launches the Activity you want, but it doesn't check for whether the user is logged in or not and hence doesn't redirect you to the appropriate pages in your log-in flow (which I believe has more to do with your Manifest). It does, however, allow you to successfully register a user and log in with Parse, which is a great start.